# Extending Mage_Sales_Order_Shipment Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

What I want to accomplished with my custom code is: **I want to send different email template, when order is shipping to customer partialy and full-shipment.**

Here is my custom module's code

Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <modulename>
                <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model</class>
            </modulename>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

Namespace/Module/etc/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <tabs>
        <sales translate="label" module="sales">
            <label>Sales</label>
            <sort_order>400</sort_order>
        </sales>
    </tabs>
    <sections>
        <sales_email translate="label" module="sales">
            <label>Sales Emails</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>301</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <shipment translate="label">
                    <label>Shipment</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <template_partial translate="label">
                            <label>Partial Shipment Email TemplateXOXO</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_email_template</source_model>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </template_partial>
                    </fields>
                </shipment>
            </groups>
        </sales_email>
    </sections>
</config>
```

and Namespace/Modulename/Model/Partialshipment/

```
    <?php
/**
 *  Created by: Me
 *  Function to split email into two template. Full shipment and Partial Shipment
 *  Date: 07-February-2018
**/
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Partialshipmentemail extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment {


    const XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL       = 'sales_email/shipment/template_partial';


    /**
     * Send email with shipment data
     *
     * @param boolean $notifyCustomer
     * @param string $comment
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment
     */
    public function sendEmail($notifyCustomer = true, $comment = '')
    {
        $order = $this->getOrder();
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        $storeId = $order->getStore()->getId();

        if (!Mage::helper('sales')->canSendNewShipmentEmail($storeId)) {
            return $this;
        }
        // Get the destination email addresses to send copies to
        $copyTo = $this->_getEmails(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_TO);
        $copyMethod = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_COPY_METHOD, $storeId);
        // Check if at least one recepient is found
        if (!$notifyCustomer && !$copyTo) {
            return $this;
        }

        // Start store emulation process
        $appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
        $initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($storeId);

        try {
            // Retrieve specified view block from appropriate design package (depends on emulated store)
            $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($order->getPayment())
                ->setIsSecureMode(true);
            $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
            $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            // Stop store emulation process
            $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
            throw $exception;
        }

        // Stop store emulation process
        $appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);

//        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $total_ordered_items = $order->getData('total_qty_ordered');
        $num_of_shipped_items = 0;

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
            //$item->getQtyOrdered() // Number of item ordered
            $num_of_shipped_items += $item->getQtyShipped();
            //$item->getQtyInvoiced()
        }

        if($num_of_shipped_items == $total_ordered_items){ ///////// I tried to call this
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE, $storeId);
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
        }
        else{
            $templateId = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE_PARTIAL, $storeId);
            $customerName = $order->getCustomerName();
        }
//        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- //

        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');
        if ($notifyCustomer) {
            $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
            $emailInfo->addTo($order->getCustomerEmail(), $customerName);
            if ($copyTo && $copyMethod == 'bcc') {
                // Add bcc to customer email
                foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                    $emailInfo->addBcc($email);
                }
            }
            $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
        }

        // Email copies are sent as separated emails if their copy method is 'copy' or a customer should not be notified
        if ($copyTo && ($copyMethod == 'copy' || !$notifyCustomer)) {
            foreach ($copyTo as $email) {
                $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
                $emailInfo->addTo($email);
                $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);
            }
        }

        // Set all required params and send emails
        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_IDENTITY, $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId($templateId);
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
                'order'        => $order,
                'shipment'     => $this,
                'comment'      => $comment,
                'billing'      => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
            )
        );
        $mailer->send();

        return $this;
    }

}
```

The module is already active, and showing in System/Config/Sales Email/Shipment as a configuration.

But, it still not working. Still pointing to Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment.php.

I would be thankful for everyone can advise me where is my wrong.